# How to use Libre office in MAC to open a document?

Tags: java, macos, netbeans-7

I am using net beans in MAC for loading a libre office OTT file.
I have installed libre office in MAC.
I am using the examples provided in libre office SDK. The example is compiled without any errors but while running i am getting the following Exception,

com.sun.star.comp.helper.BootstrapException: no office executable found!
at com.sun.star.comp.helper.Bootstrap.bootstrap

Answer (score 1):

You could try using the JNI (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface) to call the Libre Office Binary with the proper arguments.